# Unable to build Python modules in Mandriva 2010

Tags: linux, python

I am trying to build a Python module (`pyfits`) but I get the following error:

```
# python setup.py install
  /home/steve/src/pyfits-2.2.2/stsci_distutils_hack.py:239: DeprecationWarning: os.popen3 is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
  (sin, sout, serr) = os.popen3(cmd)
  running install
  error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib64/python2.6/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

I get the same error when I try and build other modules so my guess is I am missing a Python development library. I am running Mandriva 2010.0, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The module needs python 2.6 and your mandriva 2010.10 either

1. has the wrong version (check with python -V) of python installed
2. does not have Python development package (it should be named `python-dev` `python-devel` or `python-development` or something like that) installed

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need the package `lib64python2.6-devel`.